Magic square of square order containing a nice subsquare?
The Benjamin Franklin's magic square (shown at the very end) is a $16 \times 16$ matrix filled with the numbers $\left\{1,2,\dots, 256 \right\}$ with the following nice properties

the sum of numbers in each row/column is the same (2056)
if we take a (connected) 4x4 subsquare, the sum of the entries also sums up to 2056

Here, a connected $4 \times 4$ subsquare means $A_{ij}$ where the indices $i,j$ run over $a \leq i \leq a+3$ and $b \leq j \leq b+3$. This suggests a natural question.

Question. Suppose we have an $n^2 \times n^2$ matrix that contains the first $n^4$ integers $\left\{1,2,\dots, n^4 \right\}$ in such a way that the sum of the entries of each row and the sum of the entries of each column are the same (in which case this sum is going to be $(n^6 + n^2)/2$). Is there always a $n \times n$ subsquare the sum of whose entries is also $(n^6 + n^2)/2$?

(Edit: originally I asked for a connected subsquare, caduk found a counterexample, see below.)
For $n=2$, the magic $4 \times 4$ square from the Parshavnath temple is
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
7  & 12 &  1 & 14 \\
\hline
2  & 13 &  8 & 11 \\
\hline
16 &  3 & 10 &  5 \\
\hline
9  &  6 & 15 &  4 \\
\hline
\end{array}
and all the rows and columns sum to 34. The same is true for all connected $2 \times 2$ submatrices. So that would be another example of `optimality' that is perhaps a little bit simpler than Franklin's magic square. Let us do another example for $n=3$. We pick the magic square (that I randomly found on the internet)
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
47 & 58 & 69 & 80 & 1 & 12 & 23 & 34 & 45 \\
\hline
57 & 68 & 79 & 9 & 11 & 22 & 33 & 44 & 46 \\
\hline
67 & 78 & 8 & 10 & 21 & 32 & 43 & 54 & 56 \\
\hline
77 & 7 & 18 & \mathbf{20}& \mathbf{31} & \mathbf{42} & 53 & 55 & 66 \\
\hline
6 & 17 & 19 & \mathbf{30} & \mathbf{41} & \mathbf{52} & 63 & 65 & 76 \\
\hline
16 & 27 & 29 & \mathbf{40} & \mathbf{51} & \mathbf{62} & 64 & 75 & 5 \\
\hline
26 & 28 & 39 & 50 & 61 & 72 & 74 & 4 & 15 \\
\hline
36 & 38 & 49 & 60 & 71 & 73 & 3 & 14 & 25 \\
\hline
37 & 48 & 59 & 70 & 81 & 2 & 13 & 24 & 35 \\
\hline
\end{array}
which contains the first 81 integers and has every row and column sum to 369.  Here it is no longer the case that every $3\times 3$ (connected) submatrix has entries summing up to 369, however, there still exists one $3 \times 3$ submatrix, in fact a unique one highlighted above, which has entries sum up to 369.
caduk points out that by switching the third and fourth column in this example, we get an example where no connected 3x3 submatrix sums to 369. However, it still contains unconnected submatrices that sum to 369, it seems to contain a great many (328) and one of them is shown below.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\mathbf{47} & 58 & \mathbf{80} & 69 & 1 & 12 & \mathbf{23} & 34 & 45 \\
\hline
\mathbf{57} & 68 & \mathbf{9} & 79 & 11 & 22 & \mathbf{33} & 44 & 46 \\
\hline
\mathbf{67} & 78 & \mathbf{10} & 8 & 21 & 32 & \mathbf{43} & 54 & 56 \\
\hline
77 & 7 & 20 & 18 & 31 & 42 & 53 & 55 & 66 \\
\hline
6 & 17 & 30 & 19 & 41 & 52 & 63 & 65 & 76 \\
\hline
16 & 27 & 40 & 29 & 51 & 62 & 64 & 75 & 5 \\
\hline
26 & 28 & 50 & 39 & 61 & 72 & 74 & 4 & 15 \\
\hline
36 & 38 & 60 & 49 & 71 & 73 & 3 & 14 & 25 \\
\hline
37 & 48 & 70 & 59 & 81 & 2 & 13 & 24 & 35 \\
\hline
\end{array}
Since the question seems quite natural and since the literature on magic squares seems to be absolutely gigantic, I figured it might make sense to ask it here.
For reference: the Benjamin Franklin Square.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
200 & 217 & 232 & 249 & 8 & 25 & 40 & 57 & 72 & 89 & 104 & 121 & 136 & 153 & 168 & 185 \\
\hline
58  & 39  & 26  & 7   & 250 & 231 & 218 & 199 & 186 & 167 & 154 & 135 & 122 & 103 & 90  & 71  \\
\hline
198 & 219 & 230 & 251 & 6  & 27  & 38  & 59  & 70  & 91  & 102 & 123 & 134 & 155 & 166 & 187 \\
\hline
60  & 37  & 28  & 5   & 252 & 229 & 220 & 197 & 188 & 165 & 156 & 133 & 124 & 101 & 92  & 69  \\
\hline
201 & 216 & 233 & 248 & 9  & 24  & 41  & 56  & 73  & 88  & 105 & 120 & 137 & 152 & 169 & 184 \\
\hline
55  & 42  & 23  & 10  & 247 & 234 & 215 & 202 & 183 & 170 & 151 & 138 & 119 & 106 & 87  & 74  \\
\hline
203 & 214 & 235 & 246 & 11 & 22  & 43  & 54  & 75  & 86  & 107 & 118 & 139 & 150 & 171 & 182 \\
\hline
53  & 44  & 21  & 12  & 245 & 236 & 213 & 204 & 181 & 172 & 149 & 140 & 117 & 108 & 85  & 76  \\
\hline
205 & 212 & 237 & 244 & 13 & 20  & 45  & 52  & 77  & 84  & 109 & 116 & 141 & 148 & 173 & 180 \\
\hline
51  & 46  & 19  & 14  & 243 & 238 & 211 & 206 & 179 & 174 & 147 & 142 & 115 & 110 & 83  & 78  \\
\hline
207 & 210 & 239 & 242 & 15 & 18  & 47  & 50  & 79  & 82  & 111 & 114 & 143 & 146 & 175 & 178 \\
\hline
49  & 48  & 17  & 16  & 241 & 240 & 209 & 208 & 177 & 176 & 145 & 144 & 113 & 112 & 81  & 80  \\
\hline
196 & 221 & 228 & 253 & 4  & 29  & 36  & 61  & 68  & 93  & 100 & 125 & 132 & 157 & 164 & 189 \\
\hline
62  & 35  & 30  & 3   & 254 & 227 & 222 & 195 & 190 & 163 & 158 & 131 & 126 & 99  & 94  & 67  \\
\hline
194 & 223 & 226 & 255 & 2  & 31  & 34  & 63  & 66  & 95  & 98  & 127 & 130 & 159 & 162 & 191 \\
\hline
64  & 33  & 32  & 1   & 256 & 225 & 224 & 193 & 192 & 161 & 160 & 129 & 128 & 97  & 96  & 65  \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

Switch columns 3 and 4 in the $n=3$. This does not disprove 1 though.

So, you're not requiring the daigonals to have the magic sum?

Right, no such requirement.  I guess it's then technically a "semimagic square" though the terminology seems to be a bit ambiguous.  If it helps with a proof, I'd also be interested in the "magic" variant. It's not clear to me whether the diagonals change much.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&3&14&16\\6&13&10&5\\12&11&2&9\\15&7&8&4\end{pmatrix}$$ seems to be a counterexample. I checked all $4\times4$ squares and found $16$ such counterexamples, not counting rotations and permutations of rows or columns. If you add the requirement that the two main diagonals also add to the magic number, then there are no counterexamples for $n=2$.

Thanks, I think that's probably a good indication that no such result can hold in general.

Some observations regarding 4×4 and 5×5[sic] magic squares:

As noted by anankElpis, all proper 4×4 magic squares have at least some 2×2 blocks that will also give the magic sum. If no such blocks exist the square is not actually magic; in anankElpis's answer the square lacks the proper diagonal sum. Among the submatrices that always give the magic sum is the set of four corners, which constitute a 2×2 submatrix that's wrapped around the edges. See the example below with the corners rendered in blue adding up to $34$.

$\begin{array}{cccc}
\color{blue}{1}&15&14&\color{blue}{4}\\12&6&7&9\\8&10&11&5\\\color{blue}{13}&3&2&\color{blue}{16}\end{array}$

Pandiagonal 4×4 squares, in addition to giving the maguc sum for all connected 2×2 blocks (including wrapped ones) also give this sum with alternant submatrices where the elements are two spaces from one another. The square at the Patshavnath Temple is an example:

$\begin{array}{cccc}
\color{blue}{7}&12&\color{blue}1&14\\2&13&8&11\\\color{blue}{16}&3&\color{blue}{10}&5\\9&6&15&4\end{array}$

The number 5 is, of course, not a perfect square. But 5×5 pandiagonal magic squares give the magic sum in centered square, or quincunx, patterns. One such pattern consists of the four corners like the 4×4 case, but this time also the center element.

$\begin{array}{ccccc}\color{blue}{23}&6&19&2&\color{blue}{15}\\4&12&25&8&16\\10&18&\color{blue}1&14&22\\11&24&7&20&3\\\color{blue}{17}&5&13&21&\color{blue}9\end{array}$
